# codeigniter trying to access session data from view using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session

Framework: CodeIgniter 2.0

I am trying access session data setup in model from view.

This is the code I am testing in view:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    var num_records = '$this->session->userdata("number_Of_Records_session")';
    alert(num_records);
    if(elem.value.length > 0){
      alert(helperMsg);
      elem.focus();
      return false;
    }else{
      window.location="/path/";
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

When I use PHP code I could retrieve the value from session and display it.

```
<?php 
    $numberOfRecords_session = 
    $this->session->userdata('number_Of_Records_session');
    echo "Num records:".$numberOfRecords_session;
?>
```

But in javascript this line

```
var num_records = '$this->session->userdata("number_Of_Records_session")';
```

print this message in alert box:

```
$this->session->userdata("number_Of_Records_session")
```

Any advice to retrieve value in javascript and show it alert box is appreciate.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for editing my code. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access your session (stored on server) from JavaScript (executed on client)
So you have to declare a JavaScript variable and define it with PHP
Like this you're defining a `string`:

```
...
<script>
var sessionValue = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('number_Of_Records_session');?>";
</script>
...
```

If you're sure that there is always a number you could remove the `"` above, which are defining the variable as string.

If you're not sure about the datatype of the `sessionValue` you should use [parseInt(string,radix)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp):

```
...
<script>
var sessionValue = parseInt("<?php echo $this->session->userdata('number_Of_Records_session');?>");
if(sessionValue == "NaN") sessionValue = 0;
</script>
...
```

Comment: Thanks again. It works. One more advice I am trying to check sessionValue  like this if(elem.value.length > 0 && sessionValue > 0) any advice?

Comment: Don't say thanks, that blurs the information... if you're thankfull for an answer, just vote up and someday, give yourself answers to others ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71749/discussion-between-marvin-emil-brach-and-user1166240).